# Не показывает файл с FTP

Tags: php, ssh, ftp

Вообщем проблема такая, не показывает файл с фтп в нужном месте.
Что я делаю не так?

```
<div id="config" class="tab-pane fade">
   <?php
      if($server['game_query'] == 'samp'):
      $config = "server.cfg";
      endif;
      $cfg = file_get_contents('ftp://gs'.$server['server_id'].':'.$server['server_password'].'@'.$server['location_ip'].':21/'.$config.'');
      if(isset($_REQUEST['otp'])){
      $context = stream_context_create(array('ftp'=>array('overwrite' => true)));
      $fopen=fopen('ftp://gs'.$server['server_id'].':'.$server['server_password'].'@'.$server['location_ip'].'/'.$config.'',"w",false,$context);
      $fputs=fputs($fopen,$_REQUEST['txt']);
      fclose($fopen);
      if($fputs):
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><b>Выполнено!</b> Вы успешно отредактировали конфигурацию сервера.</div>';
      else:
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><b>Ошибка!</b> При редактировании конфигурации произошла ошибка.</div>';
      endif;
      }
      ?>
   <form name=forma method='POST'>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Редактор конфигурации</div>
            <textarea name=txt class="form-control" rows="20"><?php echo $cfg ?></textarea>
         </div>
         <button type="submit" name=otp class="btn btn-default">Сохранить</button>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Может уже проверяли, ну вас есть доступ к этому FTP до PHP ? У вас Windows или *nix ОС? Проверяли  ли права для пользователя?

Comment: @Hellseher нет выше нет, подключаюсь к фтп спокойно. VDS Linux Debian 7

Comment: Логи ошибок читали? Вообще логирование ошибок включено? Очень полезная вещь

Comment: @ArchDemon Вот какие ошибки

Comment: @ArchDemon https://pastebin.com/Zw1vJDtH

Comment: Т.е. вам слова *No such file or directory* и *Permission denied* ни о чём не говорят?